# Detached Entity by changing InMemory to Spring Data JPA / Mysql

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to change the database from InMemory to MySQL with Spring Data JPA.
But I get a failure. And the ideas are missing, after I tried different things, like Annotation for Cascading and so on.

But here is my problem application:

My Repository:

```
package org.apache.struts.crud.dao;

import org.apache.struts.crud.model.Country;
import org.apache.struts.crud.model.Person;
import org.apache.struts.crud.service.PersonService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Repository
public class PersonRepository implements PersonService {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager manager;


    @Override
    public Person getPerson(Integer id) {
        return manager.find(Person.class, id );
    }

    @Override
    public Person[] getAllPersons() {
        return new Person[0];
    }

    @Override
    public void updatePerson(Person personBean) {

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void insertPerson(Person personBean) {
        manager.persist(personBean);
    }

    @Override
    public void deletePerson(Integer id) {

    }

    @Override
    public Country[] getCountries() {
        return new Country[0];
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getCarModels() {
        return new String[0];
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSports() {
        return new String[0];
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getGenders() {
        return new String[0];
    }
}
```

Person Object:

```
    package org.apache.struts.crud.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Models a Person who registers.
 * 
 * Person is Cloneable just an implemention technique for in-memory daos.
 *
 * @author bruce phillips
 * @author antonio sanchez
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person implements Cloneable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer personId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String sport;
    private String gender;

   // private Country country = new Country("", "");
    private boolean over21;
    private String[] carModels;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Person()  {

    }

    public Person(Integer id, String firstName, String lastName, String sport, 
                String gender, /*Country country,*/ boolean over21, String[] carModels, 
                String email, String phoneNumber) {
        this.personId = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.sport = sport;
        this.gender = gender;
        //this.country = country;
        this.over21 = over21;
        this.carModels = carModels;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public Integer getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }

    public void setPersonId(Integer personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getSport() {
        return sport;
    }

    public void setSport(String sport) {
        this.sport = sport;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

//    public void setCountry(Country country) {
//        this.country = country;
//    }
//
//    public Country getCountry() {
//        return country;
//    }

    public void setOver21(boolean over21) {
        this.over21 = over21;
    }

    public boolean isOver21() {
        return over21;
    }

    public void setCarModels(String[] carModels) {
        this.carModels = carModels;
    }

    public String[] getCarModels() {
        return carModels;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Id: " + getPersonId() + " | "
                + "First Name: " + getFirstName() + " | "
                + " Last Name:  " + getLastName() + " | "
                + " Favorite Sport: " + getSport() + " | "
                + " Gender: " + getGender() + " | "
                //+ " Country: " + getCountry() + " | "
                + " Over 21: " + isOver21() + " | "
                + " Car models: " + Arrays.asList(getCarModels()) + " | "
                + " Email: " + getEmail() + " | "
                + " Phone: " + getPhoneNumber();
    }
}
```

Here Controller for hitting /setup:

```
    package org.apache.struts.crud;

import org.apache.struts.crud.dao.MemoryPersonSupportDao;
import org.apache.struts.crud.dao.PersonRepository;
import org.apache.struts.crud.model.Person;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {


    private PersonRepository manager;


    public HomeController(PersonRepository manager){
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    @GetMapping("/setup")
    void setup (){
        manager.insertPerson(new Person(1, "Bruce", "Phillips", "basketball", "male"/*,
                MemoryPersonSupportDao.getCountry("US")*/, true, new String[]{"Ford", "Nissan"},
                "bphillips@ku.edu", "123-456-9999"));
        manager.insertPerson(new Person(2, "Antonio", "Sanchez", "mtb", "male"/*,
                MemoryPersonSupportDao.getCountry("ES")*/, true, new String[]{"Toyota", "Seat"},
                "asanchez@correo-e.es", "555-999-8888"));
    }
}
```

Now i get this error:

```
2019-12-11 15:44:36.496 ERROR 31800 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: org.apache.struts.crud.model.Person; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: org.apache.struts.crud.model.Person] with root cause

org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: org.apache.struts.crud.model.Person
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.18.Final.jar:5.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.18.Final.jar:5.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:783) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.18.Final.jar:5.2.18.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:768) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.18.Final.jar:5.2.18.Final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:305) ~[spring-orm-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.struts.crud.dao.PersonRepository.insertPerson(PersonRepository.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.apache.struts.crud.dao.PersonRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b662eb76.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.struts.crud.dao.PersonRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$23e06b9d.insertPerson(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.apache.struts.crud.HomeController.setup(HomeController.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:981) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:873) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:858) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.13.RELEASE.jar:5.0.13.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_232]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_232]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.39.jar:8.5.39]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_232]
```

@Website i got this error:
detached entity passed to persist: org.apache.struts.crud.model.Person; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: org.apache.struts.crud.model.Person

Has someone a helping hand?

Comment: Yes the Repository is incomplete. At this moment I'm interested to save/persist/insertPerson to my database. The db is created and the table is described. So it's running, but I can't write to it.

Comment: You can simply create an interface of PersonRepository that extends CrudRepository .  
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer>{}

use personRepository.save method to save to DB.

Comment: @Sudip thank you. It runs! Can I ask one further question? The Object Person has another Object, Country. Is it an own table and how can i save this in a database?

Comment: The problem was the @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO), because I'm setting a Id manuell and also a generated one.

Comment: @ publicduck 
Do you mean relationship like Many to One between Person and Country? if that then you can create a separate Country Entity class and join.
For Example - 

@Table(name = "EVENT_DETAILS")
public class EventDetails { ....Fields...}

@Table(name = "CANDIDATE_DETAILS")
public class CandidateDetails {

.....Fields.....
     @JsonIgnore
      @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
      @JoinColumn(name = "EVENT_ID", nullable = false)
      private EventDetails eventDetails;
}

Comment: @Sudip It seems to me right. I'll try it the next days and answer here, if it not failed :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO), because I'm setting an Id manuell and also generate one.

But the crud interface also helped until the next question. ;)